# Is having 'Util' classes a cause for concern?

Tags: design, object-oriented, code-smell

I sometimes create 'Util' classes which primarily serve to hold methods and values that don't really seem to belong elsewhere.  But every time I create one of these classes, I think "uh-oh, I'm gonna regret this later ...", because I read somewhere that it's bad.

But on the other hand, there seem to be two compelling (at least for me) cases for them:

1. implementation secrets that are used in multiple classes within a package
2. providing useful functionality to augment a class, without cluttering its interface

Am I on the way to destruction?  What you say !!  Should I refactor?

Comment: Stop using `Util` in your classes' names. Problem solved.

Comment: @Yannis haha, nice one.  If only it were so easy.

Comment: @MattFenwick Yannis has a good point. Naming a class `SomethingUtil` is a bit lazy and just obscures the true purpose of the class - same with classes named `SomethingManager` or `SomethingService`. If that class has a single responsibility it should be easy to give it a meaningful name. If not, that's the real problem to deal with...

Comment: @MDavey good point, it was probably a bad word choice to use `Util`, although obviously I didn't expect that that would get fixated on and the rest of the question ignored ...

Comment: If you create multiple *Util classes separated by which kind of object they manipulate, then I think it's fine. I don't see any problem with having a StringUtil, ListUtil, etc. Unless you are in C# then you should use extention methods.

Comment: I often have sets of functions that are used for related purposes.  They don't really map well to a class.  I don't need an ImageResizer class, I just need a ResizeImage function.  So I'll put related functions into a static class like ImageTools.  For functions that aren't in any sort of grouping yet, I do have a Util static class to hold them, but once I have a few that are related enough to each other to fit in one class, I'll move them.  I see no better OO way to handle this.

Comment: Sometimes I'll make them their own project and then just include references to them. This lets me maintain the util code separately and in a single place, which is handy. You just have to move every zig. :)

Comment: Check this blog post: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html

Answer (score 28):

Modern OO design accepts that not *everything* is an object. Some things are behaviors, or formulae, and some of those don't have state. It's good to model these things as pure functions to get the benefit of that design.

Java and C# (and others) require you make a util class and jump through that hoop to do it. Annoying, but not the end of the world; and not really troublesome from a design perspective.

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of what I was thinking.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Agreed, although it should be mentioned that .NET now offers extension methods and partial classes as an alternative to this approach. If you take this item to its extreme, you end up with Ruby mixins -- a language that has little need for utility classes.

Comment: @neontapir - Except the implementation of extension methods basically forces you to make a util class with the extension methods...

Comment: True. There are two places where Util classes hinder, one is in the class itself and the other is the callsite. By making the methods look like they exist on the enhanced object, extension methods address the callsite issue. I agree, there is still the issue of the Util class's existance.

Answer (score 16):

## Never say "Never"

I don't think it's necessarily bad, it's only bad if you do it badly and abuse it.

## We All Need Tools and Utilities

For starters, we all use some libraries that are sometimes deemed as almost ubiquitous and must-haves. For instance, in the Java world, [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or some of [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) ([Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/), etc...).

So there clearly is a need for these.

## Avoid Hard-Word, Duplication, and Introducing Bugs

If you think about these are pretty much just a very big bunch of these `Util` classes you describe, except someone went through great lengths to get them (relatively) right, and they've been [time](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReleaseHistory)-[tested](http://commons.apache.org/lang/release-history.html) and heavily eye-balled by others.

So I'd say the first rule of thumb when feeling the itch to write a `Util` class is to check that `Util` class actually doesn't already exist.

The only counter-argument I've seen for that is when you want to limit your dependencies because:

- you want to limit the memory footprint of your dependencies,
- or you want to tightly control what developers are allowed to use (happens in obsessive large teams, or when a particular framework is known for having the odd super-crappy class to absolutely avoid somewhere).

But both of these can be tackled by re-packaging the lib using [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) or an equivalent, or taking it apart yourself (for [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) users, the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin) offers some [filtering patterns](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) to integrate this as part of your build).

So, if it's in a lib and matches your use case, and no benchmarks tells you otherwise, use it. If it varies a bit from what you, extend it (if possible) or extend it, or in the last resort re-write it.

## Naming Conventions

However, so far in this answer I called them `Util`s like you. Don't name them that.

Give them meaningful names. Take Google Guava as a (very, very) good example of what to do, and just imagine that the `com.google.guava` namespace is actually your `util` root.

Call your package `util`, at worst, but not the classes. If deals with `String` objects and manipulation of string constructs, call it [`Strings`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html), not [`StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) (sorry, [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/lang/) - I still like and use you!). If it does something specific, choose a specific class name (like [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) or [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html)).

## Unit-Test

If you have to resort to writing these utilities, make sure to unit-test them. The good thing about utilities is that they usually are rather self-contained components, which take specific inputs and return specific outputs. That's the concept. So there's no excuse to not unit-test them.

Also, unit-testing will allow you to define and document their API's contract. If tests break, either you changed something the wrong way, or it means you are trying to change your API's contract <sup>*(or that your original tests were crap - learn from it, and don't do it again)*</sup>.

## API Design

The design decision's you'll take for these APIs will follow you a long-time, possibly. So, while not spending hours on writing a `Splitter`-clone, do be careful about how you approach the issue.

Ask yourself a few questions:

- Does your utility method warrant a class on its own, or is a static method good enough, if it makes sense for it to be part of a group of similarly useful methods?
- Do you need [factory methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to create objects and make your APIs more readable?
- Speaking of readability, do you need a [Fluent API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), [builders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), etc...?

You want these utils to cover a large breadth of use-cases, to be robust, stable, well-documented, following the principle of least surprise, and to be self-contained. Ideally, each sub-package of your utils, or your whole util package at least, shall be exportable to a bundle for easy re-use.

As usual, learn from giants here:

- Sift through these, then analyze and compare, and go back to them often to do it again *<sup>(note that I am not making any judgment about whether these are absolutely or partially good or bad, the emphasis is on the **analyze and compare** bit)</sup>*:

  - Java's [`util`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) package (which contains the Collections library) and its [.Net equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145035.aspx),
  - Google Guava and Apache Commons,
  - C++'s STL and [Boost](http://www.boost.org/),
  - Scala's [collection](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html) [library](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html) and [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/),
  - and go *[Back to Basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)* and have a look at the goo ol' lib C.
- Watch Josh Bloch's *[How to Design a Good API and Why it Matters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw)* ([slides](http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf)).
- Read and watch some additional Bloch material:

  - *[Effective Java](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC)* (Bloch, 2008),
  - *[Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/)* (Bloch, Gafter, 2005),
  - *[Creating Java Objects](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883)*.
- Read *[API Design Matters](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2009/5/24646-api-design-matters/fulltext)*.

*<sup>Yes, many of these have an emphasis on collections and data-structures, but don't tell me that's not where or what for you're usually likely to implement most of your utils, directly or indirectly.</sup>*

Comment: +1 for `If deals with String objects and manipulation of string constructs, call it Strings, not StringUtils`

Comment: +1 For API design in .Net, read the book by the architects of .Net. [Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0321545613)

Comment: Why would you call it Strings instead of StringUtil(s)? Strings to me sounds like a collection object.

Comment: @bdrx: to me a collection object would be either `StringsCollectionTypeHere` if you want a concrete implementation. Or a more specific name if these strings have specific meaning in the context of your app. For this particular case, Guava uses `Strings` for its string-related helpers, as opposed to `StringUtils` in Commons Lang. I find it perfectly acceptable, it just means to me that the classes handles `String` object or is a general purpose class to manage Strings.

Comment: @bdrx: In general `NameUtils` stuff bug me to no end because if it sits under a clearly labelled package name, I would already know it's a utility class (and if not, would figure it out quickly from looking at the API). It's as annoying to me as people declaring stuff as `SomethingInterface`, `ISomething`, or `SomethingImpl`. I was sort of OK with such artefacts when coding in C and not using IDEs. Today I'd generally have no need for such things.

Answer (score 9):

Util classes are not cohesive and are, generally, bad design because a class has to have a single reason to change (Single Responsability Principle).

Yet, I've seen "util" classes in the very Java API, like: `Math`, `Collections` and `Arrays`.

These are, in fact, utility classes but all their methods are related to a single theme, one has mathematical operations, one has methods for manipulating collections and the other for manipulating arrays.

Try not no have totally unrelated methods in an utility class. If that is the case, chances are you can as well put them elsewere where they really belong.

If must have util classes then **try them to be separated by theme** like Java's `Math`, `Collections` and `Arrays`. It, at least, shows some intention of design even when they are just namespaces.

I for one, always avoid utility classes and never have had the **need** to create one.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So, even if the util classes are package-private, they're still a design smell?

Comment: not everything belongs in a class though. if your are stuck with a language that insists that it does then utils classes will happen.

Comment: Well, utility classes don't have a design principle to let you know how many methods is too much, since there's no cohesiveness to begin with. How could you know how to stop ? After 30 methods ? 40 ? 100 ? OOP principles, in the other hand give you an idea of when a method doesn't belong to a particular class, and when the class is doing too much. That's called cohesiveness. But as I told you in my answer, the very people who designed Java used utility classes. You can't do it too. I don't create utility classes and haven't been on a situation when something doesn't belong in a normal class.

Comment: Utils classes are usually *not* classes they are just namespaces containing a bunch of, usually pure, functions. Pure functions are as cohesive as you can get.

Comment: @jk I had not think of them as just namespaces before. You are right. One just must try to give them a theme, like `Math` class in Java. Not just "Utils.java".

Comment: indeed Util on its own would be a very poor name

Comment: @jk I meant Utils... By the way coming up with a names like `Math` or `Arrays` shows at least some intention of design.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly acceptable to have *util* classes, though I prefer the term `ClassNameHelper`. The .NET BCL even has helper classes in it. The most important thing to remember, is to thoroughly document the classes purpose, as well as each individual helper method, and to make it high quality maintainable code.

And don't get carried away with helper classes.

Answer (score 0):

I use a two tiered approach.  A "Globals" class in a "util" package (folder).  For something to go into a "Globals" class or "util" package, it must be:

1. Simple,
2. Unchanging,
3. Not dependent on anything else in your application

Examples that pass these tests:

- System-wide date and decimal formats
- Immutable global data, like EARLIEST_YEAR (that the system supports) or IS_TEST_MODE or some-such truly global and unchanging (while the system is running) value.
- Very small helper methods that work around gaps in your language, framework, or toolkit

Here's an example of a very small helper method, completely independent of the rest of the application:

```
public static String ordinal(final int i) {
    return (i == 1) ? "1st" :
           (i == 2) ? "2nd" :
           (i == 3) ? "3rd" :
           new StringBuilder().append(i).append("th").toString();
}
```

Looking at this I can see a bug that 21 should be "21st", 22 should be "22nd", etc. but that's beside the point.

If one of those helper methods grows or becomes complicated it should be moved to its own class in the util package.  If two or more helper classes in the util package are related to each other, they should be moved off into their own package.  If a constant or helper method turns out to be related to a specific part of your application, it should be moved there.

You should be able to justify why there's no better place for everything you stick in a Globals class or util package and you should clean it periodically using the above tests.  Otherwise, you are just creating a mess.